# Tomcat is unable to find valid certification path to requested target after the certificate is added to JVM keystore

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm receiving this exception when I try to access a CAS server

```
12:27:35.216 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.j.c.c.v.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator - Constructing validation url: https://localhost:8090/cas-server-webapp-4.0.0/serviceValidate?&ticket=ST-2-I1EbyRdw9aOr4xTW9cmQ-localhost&service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FIDwebapp%2Fj_spring_cas_security_check
12:27:35.216 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.j.c.c.v.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator - Retrieving response from server.
12:27:35.352 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] ERROR o.j.c.c.v.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I have followed this guide https://github.com/escline/InstallCert to install the certificate... and effectly it added to the JVM's `cacert` keystore:

java InstallCert localhost:8090

[image]

But the problem arrises when I use Tomcat; it continues generating the same exception.

In the Web browser an **HTTP Status 401 - Unauthorized** error is showed:

[image: HTTP-Status-401-Unauthorized]

Comment: Shooting a bit blind here, but did you make sure the Tomcat config also uses that keystore?

Comment: Yep... It's using the same keystore.